# How to declare C array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, lex

I'm working on a simple lex program for class, and in it I'm creating a very rudimentary symbol table, just an array of strings with a linear scan for search.  I've declared it as:

```
char* identifiers[100];
```

And I'm using it like so:

```
found = false;
for (i = 0; i < seen_identifiers; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(identifiers[i], yytext)) {
        printf("Identifier \"%s\" already in symbol table", yytext);
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    printf("identifier: %s\n", yytext);
    seen_identifiers++;
    identifiers[seen_identifiers] = yytext;
}
```

However I consistently get a segfault at the strcmp call.  I'm sure I've screwed up something super simple.

Comment: how are you assigning the strings to the array? Can you post that sample code as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
seen_identifiers++;
identifiers[seen_identifiers] = yytext;
```

If `seen_identifiers` starts at 0, you never assign to `identifiers[0]` and so the `strcmp` will fault.

Comment: ... I feel like an idiot, this is what I get for writing in high level languages all day.

Comment: Nice observation. I was thinking of null termination.